# named entity recognition with spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm working on natural language processing using spacy library in python.
From input i get several sentences that i work seperatly using this

```
for sent in doc.sents:
```

for each sent i search for any named entity using .ents attribute.
What i would like to achieve is replacing the initial "sent" with a new one where every named entity recognized is replaced on the initial sentence.
Here an example:

```
First sentence: Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion
After replacing: ORG is looking at buying GPE startup for MONEY
```

Of course using a simple string.replace doesnt work since i would like to have a new spacy.Doc
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Just to make sure: The output should be a simple `str` object, and you don't care about any other attributes, or do you really want to get a new `spacy.Doc` object for each sentence?

Comment: i would like to get a new spacy.Doc...i might edit the question to make it less ambiguos

Comment: But maintaining a spacy object will lead to false (grammatical) interpretations of the text, if you decide to only replace the text, which has associated labels such as dep/PoS tags with it. Why not extract the tag when dealing with a downstream task (where you'll need a string-only representation anyways)?

Comment: Still figuring out how to deal with this: i was thinking on adding only the value of pos_, tag_, dep_ of the main token and to delete others that depend on the primary token.
Maybe i should considering to change the sentences before to work them as sents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to try:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")   
in_ = "Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion"
doc = nlp(in_)
out = []
for sent in doc.sents:
    sent_out = ""
    for tok in sent:
        ws = " " if tok.whitespace_ else ""
        if tok.ent_type_:
            sent_out += tok.ent_type_ + ws
        else:
            sent_out += tok.text + ws
    out.append(sent_out)
    
print(out)
```

---

```
['ORG is looking at buying GPE startup for MONEYMONEY MONEY']
```

Note a peculiar pattern `MONEYMONEY MONEY` where you have 3 entities: 2 of which are not separated by whitespace, and 1 is separated.

Comment: that's a start! thank you! i'll try to edit a bit the code for going without any repetition.
When we use ents with spacy 1$ billion is tagged as one MONEY.
Prob they way you did this was for saving the integrity of the doc object?

Comment: This was done on a per token basis, preserving original white spaces.